# Extracting a specific file name from multiple .tar.gz files to build one .csv file

Tags: linux, perl, csv

another newbie question..please bear with me.
I have a multiple .tar.gz files that contain the same XX.log file ( Named the same in each .tar.gz file ).
I need to extract only that specific XX.log file from each .tar.gz file and then append them in on list file named DataByDate.csv

I've tried multiple ways to accomplish this in one line:
zcat /tmp/jhoney/DATA.2015-10-09* | tar --extract --file=XX.log | perl -lne '/.{0,0}2015-10-09.{0,30}/ $$ print $&' >/tmp/jhoney/DataByDate.csv

This returns the error :
tar: XX.log: Cannot open:No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: existing now.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read `man tar`. I think you need something more like this:

```
for t in /tmp/jhoney/DATA.2015-10-09*;do tar -zxOf $t XX.log | 
  perl -lne '/.{0,0}2015-10-09.{0,30}/ && print $&';done >/tmp/jhoney/DataByDate.csv
```

Also, `{0,0}` doesn't seem to make sense. And if you really meant "append", the redirect should maybe be `>>` instead of just `>`.

Comment: Thanks mate!...but when running this...with the argument -zxf0 I get the following error:  tar (child) : 0 No such file or directory....even though I know the file is there.....idea's on why that argument fails?

Comment: Yep, sorry, the f needs to be last (or rather just before the filename $t). My fault, I'll fix it.